# PowerPoint VBA adding image to every slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a simple macro to change the font and add a logo to every slide in a power point.

The problem is that the font is updating on every slide, but the image is only pasting on a single slide. - So I end up with 30 images on top of each other on a single slide (not 1 image on each slide as I require)

I have the following:

```
Sub InsertLogoOnEveryPage()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sFontName As String
Dim oTop As Integer

' font:
sFontName = "Times"

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    Debug.Print sld.Name
    'Insert logo.
    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
    FileName:="PATH\Logo_RGB.png", _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=oTop, _
    Width:=330, Height:=330).Select

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        With shp
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = sFontName
                    End If
                End If
        End With
    Next shp
    oTop = oTop + 10
Next sld

End Sub
```

Any help on solving this would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things :

**About your code :** Try to avoid using `.Select` and `Selection`

`ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture` should be `sld.Shapes.AddPicture`

`ActiveWindow` will only be the visible slide in your PPT app.

**About the idea :**

You should go to `View` menu, `Slide Master` and edit the default layout that you use to avoid using some code! ;)

```
Sub InsertLogoOnEveryPage()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sFontName As String
Dim oTop As Single

' font:
sFontName = "Times"

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    Debug.Print sld.Name
    'Insert logo.
    sld.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\R3uKH2\Desktop\Dive zones.png", _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=oTop, _
        Width:=330, Height:=330

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        With shp
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = sFontName
                    End If
                End If
        End With
    Next shp
    oTop = oTop + 10
Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll want to dim oTop as Single rather than Integer or you'll either run into errors or lose accuracy when PPT/VBA converts a .Top value like 10123 to 10

Comment: @SteveRindsberg : I didn't see that, Thx! I corrected it! ;)

Comment: @Ali_Bean : Check the comment from Steve! It'll help you to place the image properly!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Masters? A Master will allow you to define a font and image for all Slides that use that Master.

Comment: Some presentations have complex layout so I want to preserve that, and just add in the new branding logo. Thanks though!